# If $A\subset B$, then $\text{ri}\, A\subset\text{ri}\,B$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Is it true that If $A\subset B$, then $\text{ri}\, A\subset\text{ri}\,B$?

Let $u\in\text{ri}\,A$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$\mathbb B(u;\epsilon)\cap\text{aff}\,A\subset A\subset B$$
so I think $u\in\text{ri}\,B$ iff $\text{aff}\,A=\text{aff}\,B$.

Comment: can you please tell us what $ri$ and $aff$ means?

Comment: @sranthrop "ri" is relative interior and "aff" is affine hull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A= \{ (x,0) | x^2 \le 1\}$, $B=\{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2 \le 1 , y \ge 0\}$.
Then $A \subset B$, but
$\operatorname{ri} A = (-1,1) \times \{0\}$, $\operatorname{ri} B = \{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2 < 1 , y > 0\}$, hence $\operatorname{ri} A \cap \operatorname{ri} B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks, Do you probably have any opinion about these two questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288177/theorem-6-4-1-auslender-asymptotic-cones-and-functions-in-optimization-and-varia and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286377/proposition-6-4-1-auslender-asymptotic-cones-and-functions-in-optimization-and-v/1286627#1286627 ?

Comment: @user117890: I added notes to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I presume $\text{aff} A$ means the affine hull of $A$ (in some normed linear space), and $\text{ri} A$ is the relative interior of $A$ with respect to this affine hull.

No, it's not true.  In $\mathbb R^2$, let $A$ be a line segment, and let $B$ be the union of $A$ with some point not on $A$.  Then $\text{ri}(A)$ is nonempty, but $\text{ri}(B)$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks, If this relation was right, then I could verify $\rm{ri}(\rm{ri\,conv\,rge}A)\subset \rm{ri\,rge}A$, since $\rm{ri\,conv\,rge}A\subset \rm{rge}A$ in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286377/proposition-6-4-1-auslender-asymptotic-cones-and-functions-in-optimization-and-v/1286627#1286627